# React Native / Android line break of words with hyphens not working

Tags: android, react-native, line-breaks, word-break

With a React Native Text component like this:

```
<Text style={{maxWidth: 220}}>
   This is a-very-long-word-combining-nine-words-with-hyphens
</Text>
```

IOS automatically knows where to break line, while Android keeps splitting
words randomly:

iOS:

This is a-very-long-word-
combining-nine-words-
with-hyphens

Android:

This is a-very-long-wor
d-combining-nine-word
s-with-hyphens

I already tried all possible combinations of textBreakStrategy, numberOfLines and ellipsizeMode.